# Pending Http Post Request in IE11 - while accessing intranet website

Tags: internet-explorer, http, networking, web, internet-explorer-11

Few of our intranet site users are experiencing a problem while accessing our site.
The HTTP request hangs in a pending state and then the browser throws an exception 'This page can't be displayed'. We could not find a specific pattern to reproduce this issue, but it keeps happening sporadically in different pages.

- These users are from other department and they are in different LAN from where our web-server is hosted.
- They use IE11 on Windows 7 Operating system.
- To troubleshoot this issue we used various network monitor tools (IE browser, fiddler, NetMon utility)
- From the capture files - we found that the Http request was captured in the 'IE11 F12 developer tool (network tab)' but the request was not captured in Fiddler or NetMon utility.

Capture files for your reference :

- [IE11 F12 Network report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Jnp_fTN8G2R1dLM244dE96SEk/view?usp=sharing).
- [Fiddler Report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Jnp_fTN8G2Smkwb1BKSDVsaGc/view?usp=sharing)

Note: Earlier our users have accessed our website using IE8 and Windows XP without any problem. Now their system was upgraded to Windows7 and IE11, after which they face this issue.

We were under the impression that this is a network issue but after verifying the network capture report, we are not sure. This could very well be the browser (IE11) issue.

If anyone else has faced this problem and have a solution, do let me know.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution? I have one Win7 machine that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: same problem here, Win7 + IE11. Any luck finding a solution?

Comment: We're seeing this on a pdf download, http POST is pending. Works fine in Chrome, of course.

Comment: @increddibelly Encountered the same: POST request that should start a download. DevTools shows the request as normal, but 'This page can't be displayed' gets shown. Did you ever found anything out?

Comment: I've got a similar issue as described in the previous comment. I think I found a cause for me: If the URL gets to long (>2048 chars) the error gets shown. In my case I had a too long query string. I guess the same problem exists with Edge.